# How to get rid of if-else statement clutter?

Tags: c#

```
if (Functioncall){}     
else if (Functioncall){}

if (Functioncall){}

if (Functioncall){}

if (Functioncall){ 
                 if (Functioncall){                       

                                  if (Functioncall){}

                                  }
                  }
else {}
```

Each function call returns a boolean value and depending on the return value, a set of statements are executed. 
I'm trying to get rid of the if-else ladders which seem to clutter up the code.

How can I do so?

Comment: Indent 2 spaces at a time.

Comment: This really bases on your functions. Sometimes there is no other way.

Comment: Any way of using Assert Statements to do the same ?

Answer (score 2):

You can check for the opposite conditions and return "early". That way, you will have much cleaner code flow, much less indents, and probably a bit clearer logic when you (or someone else) reads your code.

Have a look at these:

- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/118757/33914
- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/18473/33914

In your case, it would be something similar to:

```
if (!Functioncall)
    return;

if (!OtherFunctioncall)
    return;
```

etc.

Comment: The Function calls are methods which have been provided to me, I cannot modify the logic within them. Depending on the values returned by them, I've to do different things within my code. .

Comment: That's OK, you can still check for the opposite and do an early exit. For example, `if (!Functioncall) return;` and continue without further indenting.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on how your code is written, the nested `if`s can be written as one big `if`

```
if(Function1 && Function2 && Function3){

}else{}
```

If your code was

```
if (Functioncall){ 
    if (Functioncall){
        if (Functioncall){
            // the code
        }
    }
}
```

Then the  above code is identical.

Comment: You should add the note that function2 is not called if function1 returns false. In other languages like VB all functions would be called.

Comment: @rekire Oh i didnt realise VB didnt  have short circuiting. Regardless I am going based on his code which only calls them if the previous one is true

Answer (score 1):

You have some options:

- Switch-case-clauses
- Make your code better modularized. Break out into methods (easier to see duplicated code aswell)
- Check for opposite and return immediately. Might help you with nested ifs

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your functions are all returning a `bool`.  Does the return `true` mean succeeded and `false` mean failed?  If so then you should change the the functions to be `void` and throw an `Exception` when they fail.  Then the calling code does not need to check the return value.

Comment: It's hard to recommend changing these methods' signatures, they might have some design consideration in place. Also see his comment to my answer with that regard.